# How do I get the total offset of one display object between an ancestor display object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

How would I get the distance from a display object in a nested container and a root container like the stage or spark Application?

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

                       applicationComplete="applicationCompleteHandler(event)"
                       >


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                var point:Point = new Point(nestedButton.x, nestedButton.y);
                var localToGlobalPoint:Point = this.localToGlobal(point);
                var globalToLocalPoint:Point = this.globalToLocal(point);
                var localToContentPoint:Point = this.localToContent(point);

                trace("Button x: " + nestedButton.x);
                trace("Button layout bounds x: " + nestedButton.getLayoutBoundsX());
                trace("Button to main container localToGlobal x: " + localToGlobalPoint.x);
                trace("Button to main container globalToLocal x: " + globalToLocalPoint.x);
                trace("Button to main container localToContent x: " + localToContentPoint.x);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Canvas id="mainCanvas" top="10" left="10">
        <mx:Canvas top="10" left="10">
            <s:Group x="10" y="10">
                <s:Button id="sparkButton2" label="spark button" x=10 y="10"/>
            </s:Group>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:Canvas>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

If the button is nested in 3 containers and each container is `10` pixels from the edge of the previous and the button is `10` pixels from it's edge the total `x` value should be `40`. That's not the value I'm getting. The `x` value in each call is tracing out to `0`.

Comment: You likely want to do `nestedButton.localToGlobal(new Point());` (converting nestedButton's local 0,0 to the stage position), unless `this` is the direct parent of `nestedButton then it would be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be Flash API for this. So it looks like you take the two display objects and get their position globally and then subtract the difference.

Here's a function and it seems like it's working:

```
public function distanceBetweenDisplayObjects(source:Object, target:Object):Point {
    var sourceRelativePoint:Point;
    var sourceLocalToGlobalPoint:Point;
    var containerLocalToGlobalPoint:Point;
    var x:Number;
    var y:Number;

    var zeroPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);
    sourceLocalToGlobalPoint = source.localToGlobal(zeroPoint);
    containerLocalToGlobalPoint = target.localToGlobal(zeroPoint);

    var sourceDifference:Point = sourceLocalToGlobalPoint.subtract(containerLocalToGlobalPoint);
    var containerDifference:Point = containerLocalToGlobalPoint.subtract(sourceLocalToGlobalPoint);

    return sourceDifference;
}
```

Usage:

```
var sourceDifference:Point = distanceBetweenDisplayObjects(nestedButton, mainContainer);
```