# How do I position a element when that container is scaled?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have a component that I'm trying to position and it works fine when the parent is not scaled but when it is scaled the positioning is off.

How do I get the correct position?

I will try to provide some example code since it is part of a larger application but it's basically the following:

```
<Group id="MainGroup" x="10" y="10">
   <Group id="SubGroup" x="10 y="10">
      <Button id="original" x="10" y="10">
   </Group>
</Group>

<Button id="clone">
```

Then I use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40030641/441016) question or similar code to find out how to position the second button that is outside of the scaled containers.

It looks like the code I'm using works so there must be something else going on. Here is updated test code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.flexcapacitor.utils.DisplayObjectUtils;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var point:Point = DisplayObjectUtils.getDistanceBetweenDisplayObjects(originalButton, cloneButton);
                cloneButton.x = point.x;
                cloneButton.y = point.y;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Group x="10" y="10" scaleX="2" scaleY="2">
        <s:Group x="10" y="10">
            <s:Button id="originalButton" x="10" y="10" label="Button"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Button id="cloneButton" label="position me" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: When you scale a container, all of its descendants scale up with it (from the top-left by default). If you position something inside a container at 10, 10 and scale that container to 200%, the position of the child relative to the parent of that container will increase to 20, 20. You could always reverse this effect by re-positioning the children based on the scale of the parent (`child.x = childOriginalX / container.scaleX`) but this seems clunky.

Comment: The best way to deal with scaling is to use percentage width and height in addition to max width / height, this way it will be flexible and responsive. Also, try not to use x/y positioning, but instead paddingTop/Bottom..etc